# local forward declarations when using composer or storyboard scenes

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

Q. Is it a good practice to declare all function and variable names as local in the forward declaration section of **a storyboard** or **composer scene**?

The reason I'm asking this is I've come across errors like

> attempt to index some function_or_variable (a nil value)

These errors are usually scope related errors. What I'd like to know if the coding style below is good practice to avoid such errors?

```
-- forward declaration section

    -- variable names
    local mesg, ctr, initValue,finalValue,score,num_of_coins...

    -- function names
    local postMesg,checkCoins,buyCoins.....

-- forward declaration section

function checkCoins()
  -- code 
end

function buyCoins()
  -- code 
end

function postMesg()
  -- code 
end
```

I tried searching on Corona Labs Forums and came across two similar questions but with no answers

- http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/40072-question-on-best-practices-for-storyboard/?hl=%2Bstoryboard+%2Bbest+%2Bpractices
- http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/34455-storyboard-best-practices/?hl=%2Bstoryboard+%2Bbest+%2Bpractices

Can you share your best practices for usage of variable and function names **in Corona Storyboard or Composer API's**, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The approach which you are is using is good one but not the best one .Try to avoid using global functions.

Instead of using local postMesg,checkCoins,buyCoins.... you can directly declare

```
local function checkCoins()
-- code 
end

local function buyCoins()
-- code 
end

local function postMesg()
-- code 
end
```

This is one of the best approach as for as i know.